Is this question about a detached experience while playing Dark Souls on-topic?
We recently got a question about whether a somewhat detached feeling when playing Dark Souls was normal.
The current vote count is +2, -3. I personally VTC'd as Opinion-based, because this will depend on the person. I am the only close vote currently.
The only answer (+4 right now) is also subjective (I do mostly agree with it though).
Is this question allowed? Personally, I feel like this a question that normally wouldn't be, but just hasn't gotten much attention (though at least two other users with close-vote privileges have viewed the question (it's not magic, unfortunately - they left comments (nothing about potential closing/question legitimacy))).

I don't think that the question is completely opinion based (I voted to leave open, btw), OP is just asking if that is the normal experience and if there were a more "correct" way to play. Two experienced users, as you stated, commented about the game and not the question itself, that means it was ok for them too.

@pinckerman Wouldn’t a “normal” play through vary from person to person though? And the same with a “correct way to play the game”.

I mean, apparently it's common to totally miss some NPCs because they are well hidden. This, in my opinion, it's considered "normal" gaming experience

It sounds like the question could be reworded to focus on what @pinckerman mentioned, rather than the subjective "feeling the game" thing.

@comment flagger - (not naming names) generally speaking, meta is used for discussion, and we can't move comments to be under answers, so deleting a comment for being an 'answer' would just result in a loss of context and leave the discussion more confusing. Alternatively we'd could delete the discussion entirely, which IMO would be even worse: the removal of several user's opinions on the matter.

As stated in a comment on the question, I believe it is on-topic and can be left open. Based on the preceding comments it became clear that missing a large chunk of content during a play-through is a known tendency of the Dark Souls game series. Wipqozn's answer expands on this.
At first sight, there is definitely something to say for this question being opinion-based, though - as I think the first answer demonstrated. That the validation of this question was, in my case anyway, based on the initial (currently deleted) comments is not completely ..legitimate. Similar to how answers shouldn't be used to validate a question.
But, while "Is this normal?"-questions usually set of alarm bells (even though normalcy can objectively be measured using e.g. normal distribution, or a "bell curve", thematically bringing us back to the main point), here the OP had informed themselves or, rather, discovered that what they experienced during a play-through was only a smidgen of the in-game narrative. So the normality the OP speaks of is one that was demonstrated and therefore the question can be objectively answered.
It is also simply a very interesting matter and good addition to the site :)
